# VLC installation on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vlc

I downloaded the .tar file for VLC media player from its website. The downloaded version supports Ubuntu 18.04. I followed instructions, but I didn't succeed in installing it. After entering `./configure` in the terminal I got this error message:

```
configure: error: Could not find lua. 
Lua is needed for some interfaces (rc, telnet, http) as well as many other custom scripts. 
Use --disable-lua to ignore this error.
```

Comment: Why don't you use the repositories? `sudo apt install vlc` will do.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and for your interest in this site.  It might help others to tell you how to install the tar file if you edited your question and provided the actual error message that you received.

Comment: @guillermochamorro  I want to learn installing software using terminal , because I need it.

Comment: @MajidVatanParast I guess what you mean is build the packages from source. The command I passed is executed from terminal. In this case what you have to show, editing the post, not in the comments, is what error came up.

Comment: I edited post and mentioned error I encountered . @CentaurusA

Comment: As per @guillermochamorro can you clarify if you want to build the application yourself or do you want vlc to be installed from the repository?

Comment: I want to build the app myself.@AmeyaVS

Comment: @MajidVatanParast, It is not a trivial task, you need to either build/install dependency packages to enable most of the features. [Here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/vlc.html) is a reference to building from sources. But just have a look at all the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @AmeyaVS

Comment: I am confused. Too many instructions and can not understand them.@AmeyaVS

Answer (score 1):

The error message in your question says to add the `--disable-lua` option to the `./configure` command to ignore the error message like this:

```
./configure --disable-lua
```

`./configure --help` will show you all options for that particular `configure` script.

Alternatively you can install the lua5.2 package and run `./configure` without any options. This package contains the Lua command line interpreter and bytecode compiler. Install it if you are developing or using Lua scripts.

```
sudo apt install lua5.2
```

---

If you would accept an Ubuntu Software alternative to compiling VLC that you downloaded from its website, you have a choice between the vlc 3.0 apt package (`sudo apt install vlc`) or the vlc 4.0 edge channel snap package (`sudo snap install vlc --channel edge`).

Comment: If the apt package does not appear in Software Center, then [enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and try again.